# Sublime to change COLOR of highlight_modified_tabs?

Tags: colors, tabs, sublimetext2

In `Sublime Text 2` editor, we can change the "Text Color" of "Modified/Edited Tabs" by using `"highlight_modified_tabs": true` like that. It works.

But it is bright red, how can i change the `text color` of it?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11294620/183791

Comment: Hi, no, it doesn't help anything that i asked.

Comment: The color schemes in sublime text are located in your sublime packages. In the menu navigate to `Preferences -> Browse Packages...` and they will all be listed in the `Color Scheme - Default` folder.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Got the answer from `Trevor Senior`

```
The color schemes in sublime text are located in your sublime packages. In the menu navigate to Preferences -> Browse Packages... and they will all be listed in the Color Scheme - Default
```

Comment: This explains where to find the colour schemes, but not which section to edit in order to actually answer the question.

Comment: This just gives you the location. I guess, kiirani's answer is what you need. At least, that answer helped me in what I was trying to do. I am on ST3

Answer (score 14):

The correct location for these settings is in the packages folder for your installation (which can be opened using `Preferences -> Browse Packages`) inside the **`Theme - Default`** directory, in a file named `Default.sublime-theme`

Somewhere around line 570, the tab labels are configured.

They look a bit like this:

```
{
    "class": "tab_label",
    "parents": [{"class": "tab_control", "attributes": ["file_light"]}],
    "attributes": ["dirty"],
    "settings": ["highlight_modified_tabs"],
    "fg": [125, 00, 125]
},
```

You want to configure the ones whose `settings` attribute is set to `["highlight_modified_tabs"]`.  Change the `fg` property to the desired RGB value.

There are four different sections to change, and they seem to correspond to the shade of the tab background.

Note that it's not necessary to modify the default theme where it is. You can create a new file named `Default.sublime-theme` in the `User` packages directory, and store only **your changes** which will be applied after the main theme file.

I copy and pasted the four `highlight_modified-tabs` sections and modified the two that I wanted.

***[packages]***/User/Default.sublime-theme:

```
[
    {
        "class": "tab_label",
        "parents": [{"class": "tab_control", "attributes": ["file_light"]}],
        "attributes": ["dirty"],
        "settings": ["highlight_modified_tabs"],
        "fg": [125, 00, 125]
    },
    {
        "class": "tab_label",
        "parents": [{"class": "tab_control", "attributes": ["file_medium"]}],
        "attributes": ["dirty"],
        "settings": ["highlight_modified_tabs"],
        "fg": [125, 00, 125]
    },
    {
        "class": "tab_label",
        "parents": [{"class": "tab_control", "attributes": ["file_medium_dark"]}],
        "attributes": ["dirty"],
        "settings": ["highlight_modified_tabs"],
        "fg": [255, 161, 52]
    },
    {
        "class": "tab_label",
        "parents": [{"class": "tab_control", "attributes": ["file_dark"]}],
        "attributes": ["dirty"],
        "settings": ["highlight_modified_tabs"],
        "fg": [255, 161, 52]
    }
]
```