# Visual cue to know whether a file has unsaved changes in Sublime Text editor

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I recently moved to Sublime Text 3 for development and trying to figure out a way in which I can know whether a file is saved or not just by looking at it in the editor. For e.g.

- Eclipse puts a star in front of the file name if there are unsaved changes
- Notepad++ changes the tab color as red

Is there any such easy to see visual cue in Sublime Text 3 to know if a file has unsaved changes?

Comment: Like the people below me have said, there usually is a visual change to the tab when there are unsaved changes. The actual visual cue depends on what theme you are using. It could be a dot or an underline, or whatever the theme creator decided to use.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Feeling a little stupid that I didn't realize the cross turning into a circle when a file has unsaved changes.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

By default Sublime Text displays dot (`•`) instead of `x` used to close tabs when there are unsaved changes.

You can make this highlighting of modified tabs even more distinctive using following property which causes modified tabs to have different color:

```
{
    "highlight_modified_tabs": true
}
```

[image]

The color of modified tabs with this property enabled will depend on the theme you are using. If you want to change it, either change the theme or change the color manually in your settings. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17918407/1291150) for more details on that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the added tip on how to highlight the modified tabs.

Answer (score 5):

In Sublime text there is a indication on the tabs, a full circle is not saved, a cross (x) is a saved file, indicating that you could close it.

Not saved file:

[image]

Saved file:

[image]