# Edit current theme in SublimeText3?

Tags: themes, sublimetext3

I remember being able to [edit ST2 tabs colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294620/sublime-text-2-colour-of-edited-file-tab) and what not. How is it done in ST3 though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend copying the theme file to your user folder, then making the modifications there. Then, you can manually choose your custom version. Alternatively, you can override files in the packages folder. To assist with this, you can use [PackageResourceViewier](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer). I wrote it to help with viewing/overriding packages in ST3. With that being said, I haven't tried to edit theme files, so it may handle things in an odd way. So, I'd again recommend the first option of copying out the theme file, then manually choosing it.

For a reference on how to change the theme in your settings, see [here](https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme/).

Comment: where is the "theme file" and where is my "user folder"? Thanks!

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: Mac (15 characters more to make this comment valid)

Comment: If you are just changing the tab colors, use PackageResourceViewer. This will display the files as they appeared in ST2. Edit the file(s) you need to and save. The plugin will place the file in the correct location to override the built in file. Restart your editor. Also, the packages folder is located at `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/`. For what you need to do, I you don't really need the location of the theme file. Please comment if this works, I've never tried overriding theme files before in ST3, so don't know if it will behave properly.

Comment: It's odd.. PackageResourceViewer sees the theme and all its files. But.. the location where it sees them does not exist! If I try opening and then saving one of the files (e.g. settings), it actually creates a "Packages" folder and stores the file there. But it doesn't affect anything. :-(

Comment: Ended up installing wombat. Works great! https://github.com/sheerun/sublime-wombat-theme

Comment: Just for follow up, it places the files in the correct place so that they will override the defaults. Honestly, I've' never tried modifying the theme file, so perhaps there's a bug in how overrides work with those files. Anyways, glad you found a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

For ST3

1. Backup Packages/Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package
2. Open Packages/Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package in some kind of archive manager program. (make sure you have write permissions)
3. Copy out the theme file you want to edit.
4. Edit the theme file.
5. Overwrite the theme file inside the Archive.
6. Restart Sublime
7. Smile